# group by individual

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe consisting of a panel data set which, for simplicity, has three columns: individual, activations, date. Here activations is an integer denoting the number of activations for an individual at a date. Now, I want to know the total number of activations for a specific individual over all the dates. I am using dplyr for this which looks like this:

```
a = full_data_model %>% 
  group_by(individual) %>%
  summarize(sum(Activations))
```

However, this only returns the total number of activations over all individuals and not for each individual specifically. Does anyone know what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out:

```
a = full_data_model %>% 
    group_by(individual) %>%
    dplyr::summarize(Total_Activations = sum(Activations))
```

Comment: This is exactly what I meant. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: You're welcome! You have probably loaded `plyr` after `dplyr` that why you didn't get the expected result